# parent of parent - how to make it prettier codewise

Tags: jquery

so right now I do this:

```
div.parent()).parent()
```

Cant I do something prettier, and more future-proof (if something else is pushed into this hierarchy, it will stop working).

I know that the element im looking for has a certain class or attr. Can I search towards the first appearance of this instead?

Comment: try .closest('.classname')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the type of selector you need? Why not `.closest()`?

```
$myDiv.closest('.parentSelector');
```

Also, you can use `div.parent().parent()`, will work just as well

Comment: Just one tiny difference, which probably does not matter in your specific case: `closest()` includes the element itself in its search, so you cannot match an ancestor if your selector also matches the element.

Comment: thx, good to know, that could actually have given me a lil trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div.parents(":eq(1)")
```

See [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```js
var div = $(".selected");
console.log(div.parents(":eq(1)").attr("class"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-parent">
    <div class="parent-child">
        <div class="selected"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```